# VueJS: Is it really bad to mutate a prop directly even if I want it to ovewrite its value everytime it re-renders?

Tags: vue.js

The question says it all. As an example, think of a component that can send messages, but depending on where you call this component, you can send a predefined message or edit it. So you would end with something like this:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        message: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        send() { insert some nice sending logic here }
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="message"></input>
        <button @click="send">Send</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

If I do this and try to edit the predefined message then Vue warns me to "Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders", but that's exactly the behaviour I'm searching for as the predefined message should return to being unedited if the user closes the component and opens it again.

I'm also not passing the prop to the father component, so the sending logic itself can be included in this same component.

It would still be considered bad practice? Why? How can I make it better? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried passing the `send()` as a computed property instead?

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to assign the message you are passing as a prop to a variable in data and set this variable to the v-model instead.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="message"></input>
        <button @click="send">Send</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
       return{ message:this.msg
              }
       },
        props: {
            msg: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            send() { use a bus to send yout message to other component }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, this indeed solves the error, but I still don't get why I should do this since the previous solution was simpler and it behaves exactly as I want. What I really want to understand is why is considered bad practice to mutate a prop even in a specific case like this where I don't want to send the information back to its father.

Comment: it is an anti-pattern as components should be isolated from each other. this means that a component should only change its own state, and only the parent can change the props. this makes it easier to track weird behaviors knowing where the changes are coming from. Beside Props are overwritten when re-rendering. so When Vue re-renders a component, which happens every time something changes. it will overwrite any changes you have made to the props.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not passing the data to another component or from a component, you shouldn't be using props, you should use Vue's data object and data binding. This is for any component data that stays within itself, the component's local state. This can be mutated by you as well so for our example I would do something like:

```
export default {
    data: function ()  {
        return {
             message: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        send() { 
            // insert some nice sending logic here
            // when done reset the data field
            this.data.message = '';
         }
    }
}
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input>{{ message }}</input>
        <button @click="send">Send</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

[More info on props vs data with Vue](https://michaelnthiessen.com/vue-props-vs-data/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm passing data to the component, but I'm not sending it back in the example. 

I'm using a prop because it can be a predefined message, but it can also be edited or written from zero. If a user re-opens the component, the message will be replaced with the prop and that's the behaviour I want.

The thing is that Vue warns me to not mutate the prop since "the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders", but that's exactly the behaviour I want. The code doesn't stop working, it's just a warning. Is it still a bad practice?

Comment: Yes, Vue docs recommend not mutating prop data to avoid potential headaches later. If the data is being passed to this component and not being passed along to any children components you can use the computed method to attach the prop to the data object. Then modify the data object as much as you'd like.
```
created() {
      this.componentMessage = this.propMessage; 
    },
```
Another method is to send an event emit through the component to the parent, check out the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event